# when adding files to tar the tar overwrites itself halfway through the command

Tags: linux, tar, plesk

I have a command that I have been using for some time. Since I moved from windows to ubuntu I noticed a problem when using SSH and issuing the following command:

find /var/lib/psa/dumps/ -type f -name "*1510310222*" -exec tar cvf 1510310222_31102015.tar {} +

Normally this command runs on my plesk server and collects all the files in the dumps folder with the name of the last backup. 1510310222 in this case.

As the command executes, files get added to the tar as expected and it gets up to 80GB.

Near to the end it shows a warning: 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

After the warning, the rest of the remaining files then overwrite the tar. Leaving it at 80MB

When opening the tar it only has files from after the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find`'s `-exec` predicate may run the command multiple times if the arguments are too long for a single command line. Create an empty archive first and use `tar` to append to that archive instead of creating it.

Comment: After creating the tar what would be the command to add the files that contain 1510310222 in the file name?

Comment: Just like the man page says, use `A` to append to an existing archive instead of using `c` to create a new one.

Comment: Hi. I have checked docs and came up with this: find /var/lib/psa/dumps/ -type f -name "*1510030222*" -exec tar -uvf premade.tar {} +
I not an very good with changing commands is that looking ok?

Comment: this works find ./var/lib/psa/dumps/ -type f -name "*1510030222*" -exec tar -uvf empty.tar {} \; Will test to see if it sorts the original problem now

Comment: I tried using  find /var/lib/psa/dumps/ -type f -name "*1510310222*" -exec tar -uvf 1510310222_31_10_15.tar {} \;
but it was so slow it was unusable. I let it run over night and it only did 32 gb and i know it should be around 80gb

Comment: I can't let it run through the day as it slows the server down.

Comment: Change the `;` to a `+`.

Comment: OK thanks got it working find /var/lib/psa/dumps/ -type f -name "*1510310222*" -exec tar -uvf 1510310222_31_10_15.tar {} \+

Comment: 1510310222 has Asterisk inside of the quotes but it gets removed on stackoverflow comments area.